# Outer and Inner SQL Join

Tags: mysql, sql, union, inner-join

I'm having trouble combining several sql statements into a larger single one.

**Problem:**
I have a news feed and need to return all posts from accounts a logged in user follows.  I also need to join a table with two other tables to grab the username of the accounts which posted on the news feed.  I have 4 tables that will be used in this query:

**Follower** (lists user with the account it follows and type of account being followed)

*Important Columns*: [user_id, following_id, type]

**User** (users can follow other user accounts)

*Important Columns*: [username]

**Server** (users can also follow server accounts.  Note servers to users is one to many since users can create 0 or more servers tied to their account)

*Important Columns*: [title]

**News_Posts** (this contains the message, account type (integer), and poster_id)

*Important Columns*: [poster_id, message, type]

I can't figure out how to grab the news posts for the current logged in user.

Query 1: Returns full news list with correct username based on "type" 0 = user, 1 = server

```
    SELECT news_posts.*, users.username FROM news_posts INNER JOIN users ON news_posts.poster_id=users.id WHERE news_posts.TYPE='0'

UNION

    SELECT news_posts.*, servers.title FROM news_posts INNER JOIN servers ON news_posts.poster_id=servers.id WHERE news_posts.TYPE='1'
```

Query 2: Returns accounts a specific user (in this case id of 1) is following

```
    SELECT following_id, type FROM follower WHERE user_id='1'
```

**How would I combine Query 1 with Query 2 so that only news_post records WHERE news_posts.poster_id = Query 2 results. It would have to take into account the type of follower so that the correct username is used**

edit: here is a rough version of the schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48f3/1

Comment: Is the schema fair game for modification? For example, might I suggest that there be an Account table to store both Users and Servers; the table would include a type column that distinguishes between the two (or more) types of accounts?

Comment: Still in the prototype phase so I'd be happy for suggestions to improving the schema.  Also, here is a pretty rough (only main columns) schema so it can be visualized: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48f3/1

Edit: I currently allow accounts to have multiple servers which is why i structured them separate.  So it's a One to many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for all news posts that were posted by an account (user or server) that is *followed* by the user with ID *1*. You want all information about those posts plus the username or server title of the poster. This is that in SQL, given your schema ([also at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48f3/10)):

```
select p.*,
    account.username
from news_posts p
    join 
        (
            select id,
                username,
                0 as type
            from users
            union
            select id,
                title,
                1 as type
            from servers
        ) account
        on (
            account.id = p.poster_id
            and account.type = p.type
        )
    join follower f
        on (
            f.following_id = account.id
            and f.type = account.type
        )
where f.user_id = 1
```

It has the added benefit of not hitting the news_posts table twice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT news_posts.*, users.username FROM news_posts INNER JOIN users ON news_posts.poster_id=users.id WHERE news_posts.type='0'
    UNION
SELECT news_posts.*, servers.title FROM news_posts INNER JOIN servers ON news_posts.poster_id=servers.id WHERE news_posts.type='1'
) un, Follower f
WHERE un.poster_id=f.following_id
```

Modified Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a48f3/3

If this is not what you were looking for, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: That's pretty close but I need news posts returned for all users & servers a specific user follows.  Currently it's only where poster_id is same as following_id.  I would need a place to specify a user id (current logged in user id) and return all news posts from the servers & users they follow.

Hope that makes it a bit clearer?
edit: also, it selects everything from both follower table and the union but I only need to select everything from the union as follower table is only for matching news_posts with users.

Comment: @MCG - May be you can post the expected result for your fiddle example?

Comment: I'm looking for all News_posts columns (message, type, poster_id) with the union column of the username.  I am trying to figure out how to only select News_Posts from Servers and/or other Users which the currently logged in user follows and that is denoted in the follower table.  I don't need any follower table information returned as it's only for checking what news_posts to retrieve for each user.

edit: query #1 i pasted returns everything I need but it shows ALL the records instead only the ones for servers/users a given user.id follows.